# gettig value outside of function jquery

Tags: jquery, function, output

I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/jevniky/v3x5B/

```
<form id="form">
        <input type="text" value="500" id="amount">
        <input type="radio" name="time" value="7">7
            <input type="radio" name="time" value="14" checked>14
            <input type="radio" name="time" value="21">21
            <input type="radio" name="time" value="28">28
      </form>

  amount:<br>
  <p id="amountDisp"></p>
  time:<br>
  <p id="timeDisp">14</p>  
  result:<br>
  <p id="result"></p>
```

and script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("input[name=time]").change(function time() {
       var time = this.value;
       $("#timeDisp").text(time);
   });
   $("#amount").keyup(function amount() {
      var amount = $("#amount").val();
      $("#amountDisp").text(amount);
      }).keyup();

});
```

And I don't know how to get those variables (time, amount) and do some countings. For example time+amount.
How ca I do that? because I can't even display them anywhere else. Only inside function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There really is no reason to store those values in persistent variables.  Just get them from their source whenever you want them with:

```
$("input[name=time]:checked").val()
```

and

```
$("#amount").val()
```

Or, if you want them in pure numeric form:

```
var time = parseInt($("input[name=time]:checked").val(), 10);
var amount = parseInt($("#amount").val(), 10);
```

Here's code that updates the total when either value is changed:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function calc() {
        var total = parseInt($("input[name=time]:checked").val(), 10) + parseInt($("#amount").val(), 10);
        $("#result").html(total);
    }

   $("input[name=time]").click(function() {
       var time = this.value;
       $("#timeDisp").text(time);
       calc();
   });
   $("#amount").userChange(function amount() {
      var amount = $("#amount").val();
      $("#amountDisp").text(amount);
       calc();
    });
    calc();

});
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/8gRr9/

FYI, this code users my userChange jQuery plug-in (source in the jsFiddle) that detects lots of changes to a text field (not just keys).

Comment: I wanted more this: parseInt($("input[name=time]:checked").val())+parseInt($("#amount").val())
and output it to some input field, or <p id="output"></p>

Comment: @jevniky - if you know what you want, why not just use that then?  I've given you the way to retrieve the raw values on demand at any time in both string and numeric format.  What else do you need?

Comment: @jevniky - FYI, `parseInt()` must ALWAYS have the radix specified (the second argument) or it will occasionally give you wonky values when it guesses the wrong radix.

Comment: I would like to out put it in "real time" in another field. Like I did in my fiddle. You set the field and amount has new value and it is automatically outputted

Comment: @jevniky - if you said that in your question, you would have gotten an answer a long time ago.

Comment: Thank you :) I thought I'll figure it out myself :) but I didn't :/
Thanks again, it's working flawless.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add the values of the time input field, and option checked checkbox within the on change event for the time input box using JQuery. To place a value in a textbox using JQuery, you use .val() after its selector. An example Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/cbqps/2/

For example, change result to an input textbox (if you want to display the sum of time and amount in a text box):

```
 <input type="text" id="result"></input>
```

Then modify the function as shown:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("input[name=time]").change(function time() {
       var time = this.value;
       var amount = $("#amount").val();
       var result = parseInt(time,10) + parseInt(amount,10);
       $("#timeDisp").text(time);
       $("#result").val(result);
   });
   $("#amount").keyup(function amount() {
      var amount = $("#amount").val();
      $("#amountDisp").text(amount);
      }).keyup();


});
```